# How to get the content of the "Favorites" folder for any OS, if it has any, in Java?

Tags: java

I have the cross-platform `Java` application and I need to show the content of the `Favorites` folder for any `OS`, if it has any.

How can I get this property in `Java`?

Downvoters, here is what I mean:

**Windows file explorer favorites:**

[image: Windows file explorer favorites]

**Mac OS file explorer favorites:**

[image: Mac OS file explorer favorites]

Comment: Which `Favorites` folder?

Comment: try something on your own!

Comment: Specify the problem clearly!!!

Comment: @BrianRoach Of course, if there is no `Favorites` folder, no info would shown.

Comment: Do you want get respective path of "favorites" folder(if Exist) in different OS?

Comment: There's an OS with a Favorites folder? I just thought that's some registry setting for Explorer in Windows.

Comment: @BrianRoach how about my new edit?

Comment: @PhilippSander What shall I try? I tried find it with myself, but there is no results. Do you need my google search history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Explorer favorites are stored in the registry under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Favorites`.

The Apple Finder favorites are stored in the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist`. **Attention:** This file may be in XML or in binary format, depending on OS version (10.0-10.4 uses XML, 10.4 introduced a binary format, 10.7 allows JSON).

There is no easy way in Java to access these resources.

Answer (score 1):

For windows systems, the path of the favorites folder is:

Before Windows Vista: C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Favorites 
With and After Vista: C:\Users\UserName\Favorites

I am not familiar with the other operating systems, but I would assume that the favorites folder must be located at a unique path.

You can hardcode the corresponding path for each OS in your program and check for the existence of the favorites folder and fetch its contents if present. Hope this helps !